# CSS, select label with ending "*:"

Tags: html, css

Is it somehow possible, via CSS, to select labels which contains *: at the end?

Explained more deeply, as requested:

Sorry, thought it was clear enough. I have a html-label-element ... which can contain *: at the end, for example: This is required*:. I would like to color those red.

Comment: At the end of what? Example markup please.

Comment: Err, could you perhaps clarify a bit more what you mean with "labels ending on `*:`"?

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear enough. I have a html-label-element <label>...</label> which can contain *: at the end, for example: <label>This is required\*:</label>. I would like to color those red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently is not possible match an element through the content via CSS only.

I suppose you need to style labels associated to required input fields (those who ends with a `*`) . if you're in control of markup you could simply add a class `.required` to the labels or, if you're using html5 `required` *attribute* you could style them in this way:

html

```
<input type="text" id="firstname" ... required>
<label for="firstname">First name <sup>*</sup></label>
```

css

```
[required] + label { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
label[for$="*:"]
```

would do it for the name !
There are many types of selectors which you can use, for your needs it is the "attributeEndsWith".
Maybe you take a look at this documentation:

- http://csscreator.com/content/attribute-selector-ends

**EDIT:**

*HTML Markup:*

```
<label class="required" for="nameInput">This is the required name:</label>
<input name="nameInput" type="text"/>
```

*CSS Markup:*

```
label.required{
       font-color:red;
}
```

Comment: `<label>`s don't have `name`s. `for` could make sense, but I kind of doubt that the OP has inputs with `id`s that end in `*:`.

Comment: yeah you're right. And it would be really bad if he used id that start with *: ...

Comment: Yeah the question makes no sense as-is.

Comment: Nope, not really, but maybe someone needs the same, and then he finds my answer which maybe :D could be helpful at least for this person :D

Comment: My guess: He has label text like `Your Name *: |______|` with the asterisk marking it as required. In that case, he's probably asking the wrong question.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was clear enough. I have a html-label-element <label>...</label> which can contain *: at the end, for example: <label>This is required*:</label>. I would like to color those red.

Comment: I have updated my answer corresponding to your needs. labels should be used the way I did in the answer !